# Efficiently swapping elements in Solidity arrays

Tags: solidity, evm

Given an array of length 10,000 how computationally expensive would it be to swap elements within the array (e.g. by performing a swap of elements at randomly generated indices i and j) 10,000 times?

In general, what is the process by which these gas consumption estimates are made? Would this be feasible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If array is in storage each slot modification will cost 5000 gas, so modifying an array with 10,000 items will cost about 50M gas, well beyond the current block gas limit of 12M.

Currently the EVM is not very good at handling much data, it is expensive. Usually it is better to use it as a settlement layer, and perform most computations off-chain.

Comment: Thank you for the insight. For something like array shuffling, would the best option then be pursuing some sort of L2 solution?

Comment: @Leeren Indeed using a L2 solution is very popular with high gas prices. For some problems it is easier to verify a solution that to generate it. In this case shuffling off-chain and verify on-chain might work and be cheaper.

Comment: Thanks. Shuffling (e.g. with Fisher Yates' algorithm) seems like quite a useful operation that has yet to be solved on L1, it seems. I wonder if there exist any alternatives that compromise (given a random input) randomness for gas efficiency.  Also, do you have any good resources for looking up gas prices for common operations? Thank you!

Comment: @Leeren If you have another doubt it is better to create a new question. For the opcode pricing see https://github.com/crytic/evm-opcodes. It is better to write the code an evaluate the gas consumption with [estimateGas](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth.html#estimategas) api.

Comment: Great stuff, thanks! Will do.